# Why is my custom post type slider only displaying the latest slide?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, slideshow

after a search throughout the already asked questions I couldn't come to a solution to my problem, this one is the closest I found: [My custom post type displays the [latest post]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180639/my-custom-post-type-displays-the-same-page-the-latest-post)

I had a slider built into the homepage, but I have noticed that after a while of it working fine, it now only displays the latest post type.

Here is the current code for the slider:

```
<div class="half slide-container">
            <ul class="slider">
                <?php
                    $slides = get_posts( array(
                        'numberposts' => 6,
                        'post_type' => 'slides',
                        'orderby' => 'post_date'
                    ) );
                    foreach( $slides as $post ) :
                        setup_postdata( $post );
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'numberposts' => null,
                            'post_status' => null,
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID
                        ); 
                    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                ?>
                    <li data-background="http://www.serps.co.uk/cdn/PG/background14.png">
                        <?php the_content(  ); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm relatively new to .php, but I thought I had spotted a couple of syntax errors but the slider still remained broken.

I changed it to this to no avail:

```
<div class="half slide-container">
            <ul class="slider">
                <?php
                    $slides = get_posts( array(
                        'numberposts' => '3',
                        'post_type' => 'slides',
                        'orderby' => 'post_date'
                    ) );
                    foreach( $slides as $post ) :
                        setup_postdata( $post );
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                            'numberposts' => '3',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'orderby' => 'post_date',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'post_parent' => $post->ID
                        ); 
                    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                ?>
                    <li data-background="http://www.serps.co.uk/cdn/PG/background14.png">
                        <?php the_content(  ); ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

You can view this live on the website here: [Polesworth Garage](http://www.polesworth-garage.com)

Comment: Also - could someone point me to support / forum rules please?

Comment: Check out [help] for all rules, help and basic info, also, take the [tour] ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your slider looks fine. It just doesn't work because the JavaScript on the page is broken elsewhere - namely on your search facility:

```
Timestamp: 2015-10-12, 10:51:50 AM
Error: TypeError: tree[x] is undefined
Source File: http://www.polesworth-garage.com/
Line: 1200
```

Comment: Is the slider fine before I made my adjustments - is it just the JS I need to look into? I've never worked with JS, but I will look into this as my first point of attack :-)

Comment: If you look at your source code you'll see all of the slides are there, they are just not sliding. A javascript error in one place can break javascript everywhere on the page.